# Failed: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("s="navbar-nav" >

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Getting started with testing in angular but this what i get after running ng test for the first time. I haven't added any tests

```
 Failed: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("s="navbar-nav" >
                <li class="list-item" style="margin-top:20px;">
                        <a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="[{ outlets: {rightdiv: ['addProduct'] } }]" skipLocationChange>
                           "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/ManageProductsComponent.html@17:23
    Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'fa-icon'.
    1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component and it has 'icon' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("]="[{ outlets: {rightdiv: ['addProduct'] } }]" skipLocationChange>
                            <fa-icon [ERROR ->][icon]="faBook" size="2x" class="icon"></fa-icon>
                            Add Product
                   "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/ManageProductsComponent.html@18:33
    'fa-icon' is not a known element:
    1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("outerLink]="[{ outlets: {rightdiv: ['addProduct'] } }]" skipLocationChange>
                            [ERROR ->]<fa-icon [icon]="faBook" size="2x" class="icon"></fa-icon>
                            Add Product
          "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/ManageProductsComponent.html@18:24
    Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("
                </li>
            <li class="list-item" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="[{ outlets: {rightdiv: ['']} }]" skipLocationChange>
                <fa-icon [icon]="faEdi"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/ManageProductsComponent.html@23:15
    Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'fa-icon'.
    1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component and it has 'icon' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("         <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: {rightdiv: ['']} }]" skipLocationChange>
                <fa-icon [ERROR ->][icon]="faEdit" size="2x" class="icon"></fa-icon>
                    Manage Products
                </a>
```

Comment: did you add `RouterModule` to you `spec` file that the cli generates?

Comment: Added it, says Failed: Unexpected module 'RouterModule' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Comment: Check Athanasios Kataras answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic creation unit tests are included by default in your spec.ts files.

Wherever you have routerlinks you need to add the following to your imports section:

```
imports: [ RouterTestingModule ]
```

If you want to do more specific testing with mock routes, you can configure it like this

```
describe('component: TestComponent', function () {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
         { path: '', component: OtherTestComponent }
        ])
      ],
      declarations: [ TestComponent, OtherTestComponent, MockFaIconComponent  ]
    });
  });
});
```

You also need to declare fa-icon component or the module that includes it or a mock fa-icon component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'fa-icon',
  template: '<p>Mock fa icon Component</p>'
})
class MockFaIconComponent {
   @Input()
   icon: any;
}
```

There is also a mock component implementation that will make your life easier. [ng-mocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks)

Comment: Works fine.Thanks